# Encode GenericData.Record field separately as encoded key

Tags: avro

I am trying to use Avro to encode key / value pairs, but can't figure out how to encode just a single field in a schema / GenericData.Record in order to make the key.

Take this simple schema:

```
{"name":"TestRecord", "type":"record", "fields":[
  {"name":"id", "type":"long"},
  {"name":"name", "type":"string"},
  {"name":"desc", "default":null, "type":["null","string"]}
]}
```

I am encoding records like this:

```
val testRecordSchema = schemaParser.parse(testRecordSchemaString)
val writer = new GenericDatumWriter[GenericRecord](testRecordSchema)
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(baos, null)
val record = new org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record(schema)
record.put("id", 1L)
record.put("name", "test")
writer.write(record, encoder)
encoder.flush
```

But now say I wanted to encode separately just the `id` field, to use as the key, and I want to do it by name because sometimes I want to use the `name` field as the key instead of the `id`.

I tried multiple permutations of `GenericDatumWriter`. `GenericDatumWriter` has a method called `writeField` that looks promising, but it is `protected`. Otherwise it looks like you have to write complete records.

I could wrap my field in a new record type defined in a new schema, for example:

```
{"name":"TestRecordKey", "type":"record", "fields":[
  {"name":"id", "type":"long"}
]}
```

I'm 100% sure I can make that work, but then I have to create a new record type and manage it for every key field. That's not minor, and it really seems like there should be some more simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it wasn't that difficult just to create a new record-type schema with only one field -- the field I want to use as the key, like the example I have above:

```
{"name":"TestRecordKey", "type":"record", "fields":[
  {"name":"id", "type":"long"}
]}
```

I do it on the fly, as I initialize my `Schema.Parser` with the payload schemas -- I just create the key schema based on the payload schema programmatically.

Was hoping for a less long-hand solution, but this works. I'll still upvote and accept any solution that is cleaner.